# How to get the sum of datagridview columns in C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015

Am trying to calculate for the sum of datagridview columns data and show results in another column in windows form application using C#. My code is as:

```
  private void dataGridView1_CellEndEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
  {            
        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
        {
               row.Cells[dataGridView1.Columns["Total Test"].Index].Value = (Convert.ToDouble(row.Cells[dataGridView1.Columns["Facillity"].Index].Value) + Convert.ToDouble(row.Cells[dataGridView1.Columns["Number Tested"].Index].Value) + Convert.ToDouble(row.Cells[dataGridView1.Columns["Total HIV Positive new and old"].Index].Value));
        }

  }
```

Am trying to add values of "Facillity", "Number Tested" and "Total HIV Positive new and old" and show the sum in "Total Test". But when I run the code I get this exception :
"Object reference not set to an instance of an object". Please any help.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are not using the correct values for your column names.
For example, this code:

```
row.Cells[dataGridView1.Columns["Total Test"].Index].Value
```

Is not going to return a column, since the string "Total Test" is neither a column index or a column name (a column name cannot have spaces). It looks like you are trying to use the column header text. Change it to:

```
row.Cells[0].Value
```

(where 0 is the index of the column)

Or:

```
row.Cells["colTotalTest"].Value
```

(where colTotalTest is the name of the column)

And do the same for all references to columns.

Comment: Thank so much. It worked when I used the index.

Comment: Please I want to ask if there is a way to progammatically insert into different tables in SQL database from the same form in Visual Studio. Thanks

Comment: Great! Glad that worked! Please mark the answer as the accepted answer.

Comment: Please I also want to sum all the rows and show the results in the last row of each column in the datagridview (with the same column names), but am finding it difficult. Need help. Thanks.